# Want to print an error message in case of exception, but have to return a value from method

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that receives a string and then returns an enum. I want to print an error message if the string matches none of the regexes. The only problem is that the method requires me to return something. I could return null, but that means I have to check for null once the enum has been returned. I was wondering if there was an easy and more conventional way to handle this? I want to catch the exception as I don't want the program to crash.

````
public static Direction getDirection(String direction) {
       try {
           direction = direction.toLowerCase();
           if (direction.matches("go\s+[n]|go\s+north|north|[n]")) {
               return NORTH;
           } else if (direction.matches("go\s+[s]|go\s+south|south|[s]")) {
               return SOUTH;
           } else if (direction.matches("go\s+[w]|go\s+west|west|[w]")) {
               return WEST;
           } else if (direction.matches("go\s+[e]|go\s+east|east|[e]")) {
               return EAST;
           } else {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException();
           }
       }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException unknownCommand) {
            System.out.println("Unknown Command");
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: *the method requires me to return something* Normally, you do exactly what you said and throw the exception out of the method. Instead of using `try/catch`, just insert your `println` statement before the throw and let the exception escape. (Note that it's also polite to other developers, including future you, to use a message like `"unknown direction " + direction`.)

Comment: That shuts down the program though, doesn't it? I want the user to try a different String if they get the error message without having to restart the program.

Comment: You can catch the exception in the code that calls this; exceptions "roll up" the stack. It only terminates your program if you never catch it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `null`. Java does not guarantee that a given object is not null at a given point in time, so you actually need to do null-checks frequently if you really want to avoid NPEs at all costs.

If you definitely want to avoid `null`, then I would go with a new Enum value for Direction. Something like UNDEFINED or UNDETERMINED or UNKNOWN or INVALID.

Comment: *Java does not guarantee that a given object is not null at a given point in time, so you actually need to do null-checks frequently* - what does this mean?

Comment: It means that you can check for a variable to be not null in a given method and that when you call another method you would likely need to check if it is null or not again if you really want to avoid NPEs at all costs. If you compare it with Kotlin, there is nothing in Java like "?", let's call it the nullability operator, that tells you if a reference might or not be null.